# rails chartkick gchart remove value on hover (tooltip)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization, tooltip, chartkick, gchart

I am using chartick and wanted to remove the word value(image below) from the tooltip on hover. So I will have Thu 33,406 instead of Thu value: 33,406
[image]
Is it possible since I am not using google chart directly?

Comment: you can add a custom tooltip to the data used to draw the chart, using a [tooltip column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#tooltiprole)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using highcharts.

```
<%= pie_chart $top_10_mention.reverse, adapter: "highcharts", id:"mention",  colors: "#4B83B4", download: "mention", refresh: 60,
library: { 
    style: {color: "blue", fontSize: 10},
    tooltip: {pointFormat: "<b>{point.y}</b>"},
    chartArea: {left: "2", top: "5", width: "70%", right: "30"},
    legend: { position: "right", maxLines: 10, textStyle: {color: "blue", fontSize: 10}},
    colors: ["#C2F4FF", "#82B6FF", "#ec8f6e", "#0099FF", "#F76161", "#76BDD1", "#E53434", "#005F9D", "#FFC2C2", "#5D90EC"]
  }
%>
```

tooltip: {pointFormat: "**{point.y}**"},